# Is there a way to hotlink images from a Box account

Tags: box-api

I would like to view images on my box account natively inside a simple rails `app`. The goal is to run a slide-show with these images. I looked for the necessary parameters to pass each images relative `url` into a `<img source>` tag. It appears that I can only download images, or view them from within the Box application.

Is this accurate, or did I miss something within the Box `API` documentation?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a shared link for a file, there is a `download_url` attribute that can be used to link directly to the file.

http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-create-a-shared-link-for-a-file